# ¿Cómo usar v-for en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Hola tengo un problema a devolver datos desde mi controlador y mostrarlo en la vista ya que no aparece y no se cual es mi problema ya que usando la extensión de vue puedo visualizar que si me devuelve la data, esté es mi código:

Este es mi vista:

```
 <tbody>
   <tr v-for="item in reservasDatatable" :key="item.id">                                                                   
      <td class="text-right"> {{item.start_date}}</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Este es el codigo que utilizo en Vue:

```
 reservasTable(){
                 axios.get('/obtener-reservas-table').then((response)=>{
                    
                    this.reservasDatatable = response.data;
                }).catch(error=>{
                    console.log('Error en el Servidor');
                })
            },
```

Este es mi controlador:

```
 public function getReservasTable()
    {        
        $reservas = DB::table('clientes')->Join('matriculas', 'clientes.id', '=', 'matriculas.id_cliente')->Join('reservas', 'reservas.id_matricula', '=', 'matriculas.id')->Join('actividads', 'reservas.id_actividad', '=', 'actividads.id')->select('reservas.id','clientes.nombres','clientes.apellidos','actividads.start_date','actividads.tipo_actividad')->whereRaw('month(actividads.start_date) = month(now())')->whereRaw('year(actividads.start_date) = year(now())')->get();
        
        return response()->json($reservas);

    }
```

Aquí es donde se muestra mi data:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: yo me lleve tu tabla a codesandbox, le pase un array de objetos y anduvo perfecto. Podrias mostrar qué error te sale en la consola?

Comment: otra cosa , te recomiendo que no uses id como :key para iterar. Si bien la idea es que ese valor nunca se repita, podes hacer ``v-for="(item,index) in array" :key="index"``. Siempre se le puede pasar un índice como segundo argumento e iterar con eso. (Si tuvieras dos personas con el mismo ID probablemente no funcione tu codigo, justamente por eso. Con index te aseguras que no pase)